# PHP/MYSQL Get data from the database for each specific user assigned

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making project doctor appointment system and have 1 admin 3 normal users  (doctors)assigned.

For each doctor, I want to only show to them the appointments specifically assigned to them to load on their dashboard. Appointment that was not assigned to them will not be listed on their dashboard.

Is it possible if I can insert a function when they log in? and get the data based from there ID? If so, how can I do it?

Below are my source code for admin and normal users.

```html
    <?php 
 session_start();

 // connect to database
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'appointments');

 // variable declaration
 $username = "";
 $email    = "";
 $errors   = array(); 

 // call the register() function if register_btn is clicked
 if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
  register();
 }

 // call the login() function if register_btn is clicked
 if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
  login();
 }

 if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  session_destroy();
  unset($_SESSION['user']);
  header("location: ../login.php");
 }

 // REGISTER USER
 function register(){
  global $db, $errors;

  // receive all input values from the form
  $username    =  e($_POST['username']);
  $email       =  e($_POST['email']);
  $password_1  =  e($_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2  =  e($_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
  if (empty($username)) { 
   array_push($errors, "Username is required"); 
  }
  if (empty($email)) { 
   array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
  }
  if (empty($password_1)) { 
   array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
  }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
   array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

   if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
    $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
        VALUES('$username', '$email', '$user_type', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['success']  = "New user successfully created!!";
    header('location: home.php');
   }else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_type, password) 
        VALUES('$username', '$email', 'user', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);

    // get id of the created user
    $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

    $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id); // put logged in user in session
    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');    
   }

  }

 }

 // return user array from their id
 function getUserById($id){
  global $db;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $user;
 }

 // LOGIN USER
 function login(){
  global $db, $username, $errors;

  // grap form values
  $username = e($_POST['username']);
  $password = e($_POST['password']);

  // make sure form is filled properly
  if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  // attempt login if no errors on form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
    // check if user is admin or user
    $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

     $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
     $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
     header('location: dashboard.php');    
    }else{
     $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
     $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

     header('location: doctordashboard.php');
    }
   }else {
    array_push($errors, "Invalid username or password");
   }
  }
 }

 function isLoggedIn()
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }

 function isAdmin()
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }

 // escape string
 function e($val){
  global $db;
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
 }

 function display_error() {
  global $errors;

  if (count($errors) > 0){
   echo '<div class="error">';
    foreach ($errors as $error){
     echo $error .'<br>';
    }
   echo '</div>';
  }
 }

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: md5 should not be used anny more for password hashing.. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.. if the hash is not salted "decrypting" off md5 is easy because off large existing rainbow tables or powerful GPU's which brufeforce 1 milion+ or more guesses per second  depending on the GPU chip... Besides your code is prone to SQL injections..

Comment: Then you should add to the appointment table a field with user_id for refference and when showing appointments you fetch them based on user_id

Comment: Where do you attempt the read out of the appointments?

Comment: This isn't what you're asking, but with your MySQLi query, you should consider using `bind_param` to protect yourself from various exploits, where attackers could inject their own query code into yours. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the comments. I’m new to php if you could me some hint about how to secure the password to start with that woule be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @ChibaAndrei I already have table built called bookings i’m just not sure how to start with to fetch the data based from the user id.

Comment: @DieterKräutl probably when they login then they will redirect to a dashboard where it will get the data from database based from there id or doctor and display onto the dashboard.

Comment: well you fetch the bookings based on the `$_SESSION['user']['id'] or how you set it up.

Comment: @Red Thze Answer is yes it is possible. But We can't help you any further if you don't show us the code where you attempt to do that.